Cannot Open streams (for reading files) in Blazor Server App
I have a Blazor Server app, that's acting as a Teams App. The problem is that I can't read files uploaded through this component:
<InputFile class="form-control mb-4" OnChange="@OnInputFileChange" multiple />

These versions of OnInputFileChange:
private async Task OnInputFileChange(InputFileChangeEventArgs e)
{
    IBrowserFile fi = e.File;
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
    await fi.OpenReadStream(fi.Size).CopyToAsync(stream);
}

private async Task OnInputFileChange(InputFileChangeEventArgs e)
{
    await using FileStream fs = new(path, FileMode.Create);
    await browserFile.OpenReadStream().CopyToAsync(fs);
}

is just one of many iterations, but the issue is always the same:
No bytes or data can be read from the file and it always fails to read the stream and thereby fails to copy to another stream. I get the files metadata, but cannot read from it.
I have tried to increase the message size in program.cs: (The file I am uploading is 8KB)
builder.Services.AddSignalR(options =>
    {
        options.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
        options.MaximumReceiveMessageSize = 102400000; // 100 MB
    });

I have tried to make a hub and do this:
app.MapHub<FileUploadHub>("/fileUploadHub", options =>
    {
        options.ApplicationMaxBufferSize = 102400000; // 100 MB
        options.TransportMaxBufferSize = 102400000;   // 100 MB
        options.LongPolling.PollTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
    });

Each time I create a new stream I also get this:
ReadTimeout = 'stream.ReadTimeout' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
WriteTimeout = 'stream.WriteTimeout' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'

Be it MemoryStream or Another kind of stream. I cannot open a stream and read data.
I have done a similar thing in Blazor WebAssembly without issue, so I suspect Blazor Server App.

The cod elooks OK, so what is your RenderMode here?

RenderMode is InteractiveServer. I tried to create a new teams app project, which uses Blazor Server and here stream reading works. So I am currently trying to copy over files from the old project to the new, to see if the error occurs again due to some other code, that is not obvious.

So I had this in my Component that was doing the file upload / stream reading:
<script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>

And removing that solved the problem. I have Idea why though. If anybody have some insight that would be appreciated.
